# Взаимосвязь переменных в коде

Tags: python

Есть ли готовые решения для поиска влияния переменных в коде на python?
Например, есть код:

```
def Prm (a,b):
  R = a + 5
  K = R
  return K
T = Prm(c,4) + a
```

В данном случае T зависит от переменных a, с.

Comment: Логично! А вы что хотите?

Comment: Как автоматизировано находить такие взаимосвязи?

Comment: В pycharm, допустим, зажимаете ctrl и тыкаете на переменную(там, где она объявлена) и вам покажет, в каких строках переменная используется. Если ткнуть там, где переменная используется, то покажет, где объявлена

Comment: В общем случае это невозможно, какое-нибудь `T = Prm(globals()[input()],4) + globals()[input()]` проанализировать уже не получится

Comment: Я с этого начал, но проект большой одна переменная связана с несколькими другими, они ещё с другими и это растет в геометрической прогрессии.

Comment: Вы хотите построить граф зависимостей переменных программы. А зачем он нужен?

Comment: Понять какие переменные влияют на интересующую меня целевую переменную, возможно будут зависимости которых не должно быть, на основание этих знаний проводить тестирование

Comment: Мне кажется, что для тестирования, вы пошли не тем путем...